# use <td> int tab @ jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

i want to use td in the tab ( jquery) and i use this :

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" 
       background="images/img_009.gif">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" align="right" valign="top">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <td width="92" align="right" valign="top">
            <a href="#tabs-1">
              <img src="images/tab6.jpg" width="92" height="73" border="0">
            </a>
          </td>
        </li>
        <li>
          <td width="92" align="right" valign="top">
            <a href="#tabs-2">
              <img src="images/tab5.jpg" width="88" height="62"  border="0" >
            </a>
          <td>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but my tabs dosen't work . when i remove td in li all thing is ok .
how can i use td in tabs ?

Comment: I don't believe your HTML is valid.  You have a `TD` with a parent of `LI` instead of a `TR` or `TH`.  You may want to consider creating valid HTML before using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't place a `td` inside an `li`. `td`'s may only be the direct descendant of `tr`'s and `th`'s. I suggest using a `div` instead.